# How to create a rectangular box that forces me to click on an option to see more content

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I know how to register the option clicked, and how to display the next content.

What I want to do is something like this:

[image]

(Don't care about the design) and now you need to click on an option to see the next content.

This is for a website just need to know which language should be used, maybe jquery? if so any help to quit. Don't want to reload the page just the box.

I have knowledge of php and some css and html butjavascript and jquery not too much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .choices { padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px; margin: 10px; }
            .enabled { background-color: #ff0000; color: #FFFF00 }
            .disabled { background-color: #ddd; color: #fff }
            .choosed { background-color: #ffd; color: #000 }
            .options { display:none; background-color: #fffff0}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('.choices').addClass('enabled');
                  $('.choices').click( function(){
                    $($(this).attr('href')).slideDown();
                    $('.choices').unbind('click').removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled');
                    $(this).removeClass('disabled').addClass('chossed');
                  })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="choices" href="#target1">A</a>
        <a class="choices" href="#target2">B</a>
        <a class="choices" href="#target3">C</a> <br/>
        <div class="options" id="target1">You clicked option A</div>
        <div class="options" id="target2">You clicked option B</div>
        <div class="options" id="target3">You clicked option C</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okey Man, really thanks for this code. I think it's far from what I Want but the next steps have to be mine. Really thanks again it's going to help me so much.
PD: I would like to give you some reputation but i dont have the requested level.

Comment: I improved an answer and You can see my profile description to find the way to help me :) My English is not good too :)